# Angular - Prevent Element color blink on template rendering

Tags: angular

In my Angular 6 app, I have a button that should remain disabled until the user selects a row in a table.

When I browse to the component, there is a small flickering effect where the button blinks from enabled (color red) to disabled.

You can view it here (the Delete button at the bottom left end corner):
https://www.useloom.com/share/b165c30f8912420182d02791066ec9f4

The way I'm handling it is pretty simple. I have an array which counts the number of rows selected. If the length of this array is 0, the button should be disabled:

```html
<button mat-fab color="warn" [ngClass]="{'button-follow-1': true}" (click)="onDeleteTask()" [disabled]="selectedTasks.length == 0" matTooltip="Delete">
  <mat-icon class="mat-36" aria-label="Delete Task" >delete</mat-icon>
</button>
```

In the component Typescript, I've set the array length to 0 in NgOnInit but still the flickering effect is there.

I've also tried to wrap the array length property in SetTimeout 1ms function and use *NgIf to conditionally display the button, but it is not visually elegant.

Is there any better solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create an [mcve] in StackBlitz please? Will be easier to help I think, thanks

Comment: ciode plz.......

Comment: ngOninit would be best.

Comment: *I've set the array length to 0* How? Length is readonly ;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `selectedTasks.length == 0` to `selectedTasks.length === 0`

more over init your array in component with empty one. Dony you have some exception in console?

There is a possibility that `selectedTasks.length` resolves to `undefined` or `null` and this will result in `true` if compared to `== 0`.

**Stacblitz edit:**

As you have attached Stackblitz (very good!) Iv modified your code - no flickering effect.

The thing is, that you have to set button initially as disabled. It was not issue of compartision - setting `[disabled]='true'` had the same effect.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ork7az?file=src/app/app.component.html

What I did: Iv added `disabled` to button so it is disabled initially. So basicly ther resolution is just as I pointed out in my deleted answer that someone downvoted :)

But to be fair, it looks like bug in Angular Material to me. Maybe you can file an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Stackblitz is available here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjl4y6   When you refresh the component page in Stackblitz, you can see the behaviour reproduced with the icon blinking. Console log shows empty array from both constructor and NgOnInit.

Comment: Regarding setting array.length, I was referring to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length "You can set the length property to truncate an array at any time. When you extend an array by changing its length property, the number of actual elements increases; for example, if you set length to 3 when it is currently 2, the array now contains 3 elements, which causes the third element to be undefined."

Comment: Thanks very much @Antoniossss . One of the workaround I had find for another component using similar button   was to move the button in separate component and emit an Output event to the parent component whenever one row is selected. However, this is an overkill, your solution is much simpler :-) Will open an issue on Github for the same.

Answer (score -1):

You should assign an empty array to the **selectedTasks** variable when you declare it. for example

```
public selectedTasks: yourArray = [];
```

And also you can use `[disabled]="!selectedTasks.length"` instead of `[disabled]="selectedTasks.length == 0"` in you'r button.

For more debugging you can add `console.log(selectedTasks)` in both your component's `constractor() { in here }` and `ngOnInit() { in here }` function. so you can see in you'r console what is happening when component is loading.

Comment: You do know that `[disabled]="selectedTasks.length" ` will have the exact opposite effect than `selectedTasks.length===0` right?

Comment: you do know that it will throw exception if undefinefd and wont compile with aot?